# Fraction simplification in polynomial

Tags: polynomials, fractions

$\frac{-\frac{y-g}{x-k}-g+y}{\left(x^2-k^2\right)-\frac{x^2-k^2}{x-k}}$

Simplyfing fraction I arrived at this form:

$\frac{-\frac{y-g}{x-k}-g +y}{(x-k) (x+k)-(x+k)}$

I know it can be further simplified to

$\frac{g-y}{k^2-x^2}$

But I don't see how. I can't see how you can get rid of the substraction in denominator. Is it even possible? Maybe the result is wrong?

Comment: Try to factorize by $(y-g)$ in the numerator and by $(x+k)$ in the denominator and then simplify by $(x-k-1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\eqalign{
  & {{ - {{y - g} \over {x - k}} - g + y} \over {\left( {x^{\,2}  - k^{\,2} } \right) - {{\left( {x^{\,2}  - k^{\,2} } \right)} \over {x - k}}}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {y - g} \right)\left( {1 - {1 \over {x - k}}} \right)} \over {\left( {x^{\,2}  - k^{\,2} } \right)\left( {1 - {1 \over {x - k}}} \right)}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{y - g} \over {x^{\,2}  - k^{\,2} }} \cr} 
$$